# Object not defined inside call back function

Tags: node.js, express

Users can select city and the number of bedrooms they want from a drop down menu. The search should work if the user select one or two items from the menu. The search menu will be for a real estate app. When I run the code, I get the error message "ReferenceError: cityObj is not defined". How do I fix this error message.

```
router.get("/", function(req, res){
  //function to search by city
  citySearch(req, res);

  //manage the object responses
  res.render(cityObj);

  //function to search by bedrooms
  bedroomSearch(req, res);

  //manage the object responses
  res.render(bedObj);
});

//search functions
function citySearch(req, res) {
  var noMatch = null;
    if(req.query.search) {
        const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
        // Get all homes from DB
        Home.find({city: regex}, function(err, allHomes){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           } else {
              if(allHomes.length < 1) {
                  noMatch = "No homes match that query, please try again.";
              }
         var linkRoute = "homes/index";
         var cityObj = {linkRoute:"homes/index", homes:"homes:allHomes", noMatch:"noMatch: noMatch"};
         //return object instead of res.render statement
         return cityObj; 
              //res.render("homes/index",{homes:allHomes, noMatch: noMatch});
           }
        });
    } else {
        // Get all homes from DB
        Home.find({}, function(err, allHomes){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           } else {
         var linkRoute = "homes/index";
         var linkObj = {linkRoute:"homes/index", homes:"homes:allHomes", noMatch:"noMatch: noMatch"};
         //return object instead of res.render statement
         return cityObj; 
              //res.render("homes/index",{homes:allHomes, noMatch: noMatch});
           }
        });
    }

}
// end of city search function

function bedroomSearch(req, res) {
  var noMatch = null;
    if(req.query.bed) {
        const regexBed = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.bed), 'gi');
        // Get all homes from DB
        Home.find({bedrooms: regexBed}, function(err, allHomes){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           } else {
              if(allHomes.length < 1) {
                  noMatch = "No homes match that query, please try again.";
              }
         var linkRoute = "homes/index";
         var bedObj = {linkRoute:"homes/index", homes:"homes:allHomes", noMatch:"noMatch: noMatch"};
         //return object instead of res.render statement
         return bedObj; 
              //res.render("homes/index",{homes:allHomes, noMatch: noMatch});
           }
        });
    } else {
        // Get all homes from DB
        Home.find({}, function(err, allHomes){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           } else {
         var linkRoute2 = "homes/index";
         var bedObj = {linkRoute2:"homes/index", homes:"homes:allHomes", noMatch:"noMatch: noMatch"};
         //return object instead of res.render statement
         return bedObj; 
              //res.render("homes/index",{homes:allHomes, noMatch: noMatch});
           }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error on line `40` you are returning `cityObj` which is not defined, You should`return linkObj` which is defined in that scope.

Try this.

```
//search functions
function citySearch(req, res) {
  var noMatch = null;
  if (req.query.search) {
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
    // Get all homes from DB
    Home.find({ city: regex }, function (err, allHomes) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        if (allHomes.length < 1) {
          noMatch = "No homes match that query, please try again.";
        }
        var linkRoute = "homes/index";
        var cityObj = { linkRoute: "homes/index", homes: "homes:allHomes", noMatch: "noMatch: noMatch" };
        //return object instead of res.render statement
        return cityObj;
        //res.render("homes/index",{homes:allHomes, noMatch: noMatch});
      }
    });
  } else {
    // Get all homes from DB
    Home.find({}, function (err, allHomes) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        var linkRoute = "homes/index";
        var linkObj = { linkRoute: "homes/index", homes: "homes:allHomes", noMatch: "noMatch: noMatch" };
        //return object instead of res.render statement
        return linkObj;   // Return linkObj instead of cityObj
        //res.render("homes/index",{homes:allHomes, noMatch: noMatch});
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: when I run code I get this message "Cannot GET /homes"